# How to calculate different data in individual columns to show data

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I know the title may seem a little confusing. I made a spreadsheet showing all of my associates and their attendance for the purpose of calculating absenteeism totals. I need to take the data for each individual day (each column) and at the bottom of all of it, show the sum of each code for that day and percentage of that code (Late in, early out, absent, present). I feel like there is an easy way to go about this versus manually doing it. If there is a pivot table i can make to display this data that would be very helpful. Thank you!!

***Here is the excel sheet I am referring to:***

[image]

I tried manually counting each and entering the data in that way but I want to use an equation. I was expecting to be able to show all of the data in each column in a detailed way.

Answer (score 1):

This is considered counting, not summing, because "SICK", "PRESENT", etc. are not numbers, so you cannot sum them. So the formula you would use is `COUNTIF` / `COUNTIFS`.

```
=COUNTIFS($B$2:$B$18,$A20)
```

If you do want to make a pivot table, your data should be in the format as on the right of this screenshot: dates in one column, status in another column. This is a usually a better way to arrange raw data.

[image]

Comment: This answer was extremely helpful!! How would I take the sums of the data and make them into a pie chart? i.e take the totals from 3/01/2024 and show that in a pie chart?